# Adding WooCommerce custom checkout field not working in custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, woocommerce-checkout-fields

I am creating a **WooCommerce** plugin for my requirements. When I activate my plugin I created two (2) user meta fields on **User Form** and saving the data, it's working perfectly.

Now I am trying to add custom dropdown field on checkout page, but it's not working. I searched a lot and asked to `chatgpt` but nothing worked. It even didn't show me the label or heading.

Here is the code of plugin main file:

```
<?php
defined('ABSPATH') || exit;

// Checking if Woocommerce installed or not
if(!in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))) {
    exit;
}

if(!defined('WCSF_PLUGIN_FILE')) {
    define('WCSF_PLUGIN_FILE', __FILE__);
}
if(!defined('WCSF_PLUGIN_URL')) {
    define('WCSF_PLUGIN_URL', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__));
}

// Load plugin text domain
if(!function_exists('wcsf_plugin_load_textdomain')) {
    add_action('init', 'wcsf_plugin_load_textdomain');
    function wcsf_plugin_load_textdomain() {
        load_plugin_textdomain('wcsf', false, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)).'/languages');
    }
}

// Plugin activation Hook
if(!function_exists('wcsf_plugin_activation')) {
    function wcsf_plugin_activation() {
        // Adding Roles
        wcsf_user_roles();
    }

    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'wcsf_plugin_activation');
}

//=========> Delete Data on uninstall
register_uninstall_hook('uninstall.php','wcsf_plugin_activation');

if(!function_exists('wcsf_user_roles')) {
    function wcsf_user_roles() {
        // My roles
    }
}

if(!function_exists('wcsf_enqueue_global_scripts')) {
    function wcsf_enqueue_global_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script('wcsf-custom-script', plugins_url('/public/js/custom-script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
        wp_enqueue_style('wcsf-custom-style', plugins_url('/public/css/custom-style.css', __FILE__), array(), '1.0');
    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wcsf_enqueue_global_scripts');
}

if(!function_exists('wcsf_custom_franchiser_fields_added')) {
    function wcsf_custom_franchiser_fields_added() {
       // user meta field code
   }

    add_action('user_new_form', 'wcsf_custom_franchiser_fields_added');
}
```

After that I tried (Hooks / Filters):

**Code Trying 01**

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_shipping_form','wcsf_city_checkout_page');
function wcsf_city_checkout_page() {
  echo '<div id="custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . esc_html__('Custom City','wcsf') . '</h2></div>';
}
```

**Code Trying 02**

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_fields','wcsf_city_checkout_page');
function wcsf_city_checkout_page() {
    echo '<div id="custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . esc_html__('Custom City','wcsf') . '</h2> 
    </div>';
}
```

**Code Trying 03**

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_shipping_form','wcsf_city_checkout_page');
function wcsf_city_checkout_page() {
   echo '<div id="custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . esc_html__('Custom City','wcsf') . '</h2></div>';
}
```

**Code Trying 04**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields','wcsf_city_checkout_page');
function wcsf_city_checkout_page($checkout) {
   $checkout['shipping']['custom_city'] = array(
      'label'     => __( 'Custom City', 'example' ),
      'type'      => 'text',
      'placeholder'   => _x( 'Type', 'placeholder', 'example'),
      'required'  => false,
      'class'     => array( 'custom_city' ),
      'clear'     => true
     );
  return $checkout;
}
```

And much more codes. I am using `WordPress` custom theme `twentytwo` and also tried these codes in active theme's `functions.php` file, but none of them code is working. I even write `die;` or `exit;` in callback functions, but nothing happened.

I searched a lot and tried a lot of codes (From stack overflow) but nothing happened and surprised why these hooks or filters not working.

Did I miss something, including WooCommerce file etc. ?

> **Note:** I used PHP 8, WordPress 6.1.4 and latest Woocommerce. and just Woocmmerce show me this kind of warning and its just showing on checkout page only.

```
Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property WC_Order_Item_Shipping::$legacy_package_key is deprecated in plugins\woocommerce\includes\class-wc-checkout.php on line 604
```

Hope you guys understood my question and what I am facing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to the legacy checkout page.

Go to Pages->Checkout->Edit
Remove the checkout block and replace it with the shortcode [woocommerce_checkout]

Comment: Yes I done this and every thing fines. +1

Answer (score 0):

If WooCommerce support is enabled for your theme, try the following approach instead:

```php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

if( ! defined('WCSF_PLUGIN_FILE') ) {
    define( 'WCSF_PLUGIN_FILE', __FILE__ );
}

if( ! defined('WCSF_PLUGIN_DIR') ) {
    define( 'WCSF_PLUGIN_DIR', __DIR__ );
}

// Plugin activation
register_activation_hook(WCSF_PLUGIN_FILE, 'wcsf_plugin_activation');
function wcsf_plugin_activation() {
    // some code
}

// Plugin deactivation
register_deactivation_hook(WCSF_PLUGIN_FILE, 'wcsf_plugin_deactivation');
function wcsf_plugin_deactivation() {
    // some code
}

// Plugin init hook.
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'wcsf_plugin_init', 1 );
function wcsf_plugin_init() {

    // Check that WooCommerce is enabled
    if ( ! class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'wcsf_woocommerce_required_plugin_activation' );
        return;
    } else {
        // Adding Roles
        wcsf_add_custom_user_roles();
    
        // Below, your Wordpress/WooCommerce action and filter hooks
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wcsf_enqueue_global_scripts' );
        add_action( 'user_new_form', 'wcsf_custom_franchiser_fields_added' );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields', 'wcsf_custom_shipping_city_field' );
    }
}

// Required not activated WooCommerce plugin throw an Admin Error Notice.
function wcsf_woocommerce_required_plugin_activation() {
    // WooCommerce
    echo '<div class="error"><p>' . sprintf( esc_html__( 'WCSF plugin requires %s to be installed and active.', 'wcsf' ), '<a href="https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/" target="_blank">WooCommerce</a>' ) . '</p></div>';
    return;
}

// Add custom user roles
if( ! function_exists('wcsf_add_custom_user_roles') ) {
    function wcsf_add_custom_user_roles() {
        // Add some roles
    }
}

if(!function_exists('wcsf_enqueue_global_scripts')) {
    function wcsf_enqueue_global_scripts() {
        // wp_enqueue_script('wcsf-custom-script', plugins_url('/public/js/custom-script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
        // wp_enqueue_style('wcsf-custom-style', plugins_url('/public/css/custom-style.css', __FILE__), array(), '1.0');
    }
}

if(!function_exists('wcsf_custom_franchiser_fields_added')) {
    function wcsf_custom_franchiser_fields_added() {
       // user meta field code
   }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_fields', 'wcsf_custom_shipping_city_field');
function wcsf_custom_shipping_city_field( $fields ) {
    $fields['custom_city'] = array(
        'label'     => __( 'Custom City', 'example' ),
        'type'      => 'text',
        'placeholder'   => _x( 'Type', 'placeholder', 'example'),
        'required'  => false,
        'class'     => array( 'custom_city' ),
        'clear'     => true
    );
    return $fields;
}
```

It should work.

If WooCommerce is not enabled, or if WooCommerce support is not implemented in the theme, an error admin notice will be thrown:

[image]

Recommendation: you should try to choose something more explicit than `WCSF` as it can be already used by some other plugin (that why I have renamed some of your existing functions).

Comment: Sorry, but it also not working. Active theme has woocommerce support. I dig more and found that cart page and checkout page is loading with react js. I copy past woocommerce template folder in my theme and rename it (woocommerce) and remove all the code form cart and checkout files and when I refresh these pages they didn't effect. I incpect the checkout code and saw that checkout form is using "wc-block-checkout__form" tis kind of classes and much more. Did you know what the issue is, how can I stop rendering page with react js. Please guide me on this issue, I really fed up now :( thanks

Comment: So WooCommerce is not well implemented in your custom theme… Sorry, but nobody can guess by magic what is the root problem, with the provided details and information. The plugin code works perfectly with storefront theme and WordPress Base themes.

Comment: And how can I do this? please, can you elaborate this

Comment: … *"nobody can guess by magic what is the root problem, with the provided details and information"*…

Comment: Can we google meet or personal chat, so I can share my screen and show the code and precess ?

Comment: I need to do similar with the react js any idea